# Jasper subreport not showing

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am using Eclipse JasperReports Studio and have run into a problem I can't resolve.  I have a pretty basic report with detail fields which return about 30 rows.  I have a subreport I want to incorporated into the main report but when I add it nothing displays.  I have tried adding it to the Column Footer, in the Page Footer with my Page x of x fields, and in the detail field.  Which didn't work so well since it added a blank spot between every row retrieved.  I have other reports with sub-reports in various bands and they all work fine.   Here is the subreport code for the col footer:

```
    <columnFooter>
    <band height="110">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="10" width="555" height="100" uuid="34205e71-ec6b-422c-aa27-057678430999"/>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["The_Report.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
```

Any obvious reasons why this won't show up?  I don't get any errors and the main report runs fine.   The subreport works fine on it's own and it is in the same directory as the main report. I compiled it there and the .jasper file is there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that the **Subreport Expression** is pointing to the correct/expected subreport.  There are times (often due to copying and/or hand-editing existing JRXML files) where the **Subreport Expression** is still pointing to the subreport Jasper file of the original, Main report.  I just ran into this case, myself.

Make sure that

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["The_Report.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

isn't supposed to be something like

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["The_New_SubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

or contain the Subreport directory like

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "The_New_SubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

You should also verify that your subreport doesn't require data in order to display.  If it does and your query doesn't return any data, you can do the following:

```
SELECT FIELD_NAME
FROM TABLE
WHERE KEY = $P{KEY}

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS FIELD_NAME
FROM DUAL WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE KEY = $P{KEY}
) = 0
```

Answer (score 7):

I came across the same problem when using subreports.
**In the editor:** deleting the content form `connectionExpression` 
And putting `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}` in the `Parameters Map Expression` did the trick for me.

**Source code:**  `<parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>`

Comment: I think I am confused.  Where does the path to the subreport go then...if not in the expression?   I changed the paramMapExp to that listed above in the editor, removed the expression and still only got the main report.  The source code was identical: 
   '<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="18" width="550" height="65" uuid="dbffe486-b268-489c-b208-424b100acd78"/>
    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
   </subreport>
  '

Comment: I am sorry but i wrote a mistake. Delete the content of <connectionExpression>. Keep the expression and change the paramtersMapExpression to what I provided above. I'll edit the answer for future reference.

Comment: I added the edits to my answer,sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Here is the new section                                                                       '<subreport>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="10" width="550" height="93" uuid="dbffe486-b268-489c-b208-424b100acd78"/>
    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["file:/path_to_file.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
   </subreport>'     It is still not working.  All I get is the main report.  I tried putting it in the summary and col footer.

Comment: Actually, in the col footer I got an error that said the subreport overflowed on a band that didn't support overflow.  I have the position type set to float but it did the same with fixed.

Comment: The subreport only has a header and two rows returned

Comment: it did the trick for me by removing connection expression and adding $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}

Answer (score 0):

A quick reminder, after double checking that you have the correct values for all the `<subreportExpression>` elements. Make sure you `Build All` the project files.

The main report will call the compiled version of the subreport. So once you have tested and saved your subreport, click the `Build All` button or click on the Menu option under the 'Project' menu at the top of the window.

[image]

Comment: I'm very new to JasperReports, and this was my exact problem, thanks!